# Two different login page for a community

Tags: community

I want to show two different logo in community login page. Is it possible to setup two different login pages for a community.Please guide me.

Comment: Need more details, Why do you need two logins

Comment: You don't necessarily need two separate pages to show just two different logos. If you know the conditions when to present *logo1 v/s logo2*, it can be achieved in the same login page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its definitely possible to have two different login pages .

Create two different  force.com site and associate a controller along to each VF to login to the community .

There is a nice article to assist you with [code](https://appirio.com/tech-blog/create-custom-salesforce-communities-login-landing-page)

Comment: Don't know if you've seen the thread in Success Community or not, but some are having issues since SP16 with Napoli template & lightning if using custom login with navigation to the self-reg page. See https://success.salesforce.com/0F9300000001og8 for more.

Comment: @crmprogdev Thank you .I have read that .Also not sure if user here meant SFDC template or vf

Comment: @MohithShrivastava know this answer is 7 years old. In Winter 24' is it possible to do this via LWC now or still just VF page?

Comment: Seems like the VF page way can only be done on Aura framework not LWR. Having said that I don't see a way to associate two different login pages to Experience Cloud sites